# Recorder.js WebAudio API TypeError Issue when trying to load buffer

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I used recorder.js to record the user. I am trying to then send the recording's buffer to a list of buffers so that when I want to play all the sounds at once, the program loops through the array of buffers and turns them into source nodes and plays them. However, it is throwing a TypeError. Here is the code:

```js
function layerRecording() {
  var newBuffer;
  rec.exportWAV(function(wav) {
  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(wav);
  console.log(url);
  var getSound = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Load the Sound with XMLHttpRequest
  getSound.open("GET", url, true);
  getSound.responseType = "arraybuffer"; // Read as Binary Data
  getSound.onload = function() {
    context.decodeAudioData(getSound.response, function(buffer){
      newBuffer = buffer; // Decode the Audio Data and Store it in a Variable
    });
    buffers.push(newBuffer); //adds to the list of buffers
  }
  getSound.send(); // Send the Request and Load the File
});
}

//And then later on when I call this with buffers:
var playAll = function(bufferList) {
   sourceList=[];
  for (var i=0; i<bufferList.length;i++){
   var currentSource = context.createBufferSource();
   console.log(i);
   currentSource.buffer = bufferList[i];
   currentSource.connect(context.destination); 
   sourceList[i]=currentSource;
  }
  for (var i=0; i<sourceList.length;i++){ 
   sourceList[i].start(0,startOffset);
  }
 }
```

I get the following error for the iteration on the recorded audio:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set the 'buffer' property on 'AudioBufferSourceNode': The provided value is not of type 'AudioBuffer'.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it was a scope issue. Just had to move the push statement inside the decodeAudioData(). oops